# Split network connection into multiple connections

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet

so I have a bit of an odd problem.

I'm trying to run multiple programs on different internet connections, even though my computer only has a single connection (a single Ethernet cable). I was able to find a program called [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip) that can force specific programs to use specific IPs, so if you had an Ethernet connection and a WiFi connection it could assign my programs accordingly, but I'm looking for a way to do this through a single Ethernet connection to split the traffic to the programs. Is this possible? (It's also possible I'm going about this in the wrong way)

Thanks for the help! (Or for the declarations that this is impossible, it may be)

EDIT: So my post was a little unclear, I'm not very experienced with this kind of thing.
I'm trying to take a single internet connection (one router, one internet proveder, ect.) and split it into multiple as if multiple computers where connected to the network. Is this possible?

Comment: This is not clear to me. You say, "I'm trying to run multiple programs on different internet connections". Do you have multiple internet providers into your home or business? Or do you just want to have 2 programs both use the internet? What are the programs you are trying to use? Are they making connections out, or listening for in-bound connections? Try to be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you have two separate broadband ISP connections, I'd put them on separate VLANs and make the PC's port a trunk port so it can be on both VLANs (i.e. it can have one virtual interface on each VLAN).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague, so I can only provide a rough outline.

Assuming that you've got multiple Internet connections (with a router each), there are several approaches, depending on how you need to split the routing:

1. With a common IP subnet with both routers, you can manually configure separate routes on your PC, e.g. 192.0.2.0/24 via router 2, everything else via router 1. (You'll need to determine the IP ranges for the services you use.)
2. With separate subnets on both routers, you need to manually configure two IP addresses on your PC. Rest as 1.
3. If you need a clean separation between the WAN routers you need a managed switch in between with separate VLANs and a VLAN-capable NIC in your PC. The NIC is configure with subinterfaces to attach each VLAN separately.
4. You can use an additional router in between both WAN routers and your PC. Then you can configure static IP routes here. Depending on the router's capabilities you can alternatively use policy routes based on protocol, URL, ...